# Writing conditional logic using mathematics forumla

Tags: integer-programming

I'm working on an application which has a specific function which receives 2 ints: x and y. If y > x then I would like the function to return y otherwise return x - y. Just a few examples:

1. f(10, 12) => 12
2. f(9, 9) => 0
3. f(11, 3) => 8

I can easily do this using ifs etc but I was just wondering if it's possible to write it using mathematics only? to be more precise what I'm asking is: is it possible to write that function as a computer function only using mathematical operands? (no ifs or any other conditionals)?

It's not any kind of homework, just pure curiousity

I was even struggling with giving it the right tags since I have no idea to what topic this issue belongs to

Thanks in advance

Comment: $
 f(x,y)=
 \begin{cases}
  y & y>x\\
  x-y & \text{otherwise}\\
 \end{cases}
$

Comment: @barakmanos I obviously thought of that but I was wondering if I can write a computer program using mathematical operands only (without the regular ifs)

Comment: The best thing i can come up with is : $f(x,y)=y+H(x-y)(x-2y)$ where H is the Heaviside function, which if defined with ifs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible if you allow the absolute value 'operation'. This works **except** for the case when $x=y$:
$$f(x,y)=y-\dfrac12\left(1-\dfrac{y-x}{|{y-x}|}\right)(2y-x)$$

I've no idea what to do if the inputs were real numbers, but because you've restricted them to integers we can hack it thus:

$$f(x,y)=y-\dfrac12\left(1-\dfrac{y-x-\frac12}{\left|{y-x-\frac12}\right|}\right)(2y-x)$$

Mathematically, it's perfect (for integer inputs).  In the real world of computer arithmetic, we'd need $x$ and $y$ to be promoted to real numbers for the inner division, and the inner division converted back to an integer immediately afterwards $\dots$ and the rest of the operations are done as integers, the multiply by $\dfrac12$ turned into $\div 2$. Depending on the precision of your real & integer data types, this could fail for very positive or very negative values of $y-x$.

Comment: This answer seems to be the most elegant. I tried upvoting the other (great) answers but my reputation is too low for that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If both `x` and `y` are represented in 2's-complement format:

```
int func(int x,int y)
{
    int b = ((x-y)>>31)&1;
    return y*b+(x-y)*(1-b);
}
```

Please note that I've assumed that the size of `int` is 32 bits.

Generally, `31` should be replaced with `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-1`.

It might fail if `x-y` overflows (extremely small or extremely large).